# What video game is being played in V/H/S/99?

Tags: game-identification

In the 2022 horror anthology film, *[V/H/S/99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V/H/S/99)*, "The Gawkers" segment, one of the characters is shown playing a third-person game in which the player character is fighting what seems to be slow-moving zombies in an urban environment (on a paved road). There are multiple burning objects in the background. The film is set in 1999 and the character playing is using a controller, so the game is likely a 90s console game. Anyone know what game it is, and what part or level of that game is shown?

Screen recording:

[image: screen recording of the video game being played]

Screencaps:

<sup>(Click on an image to view the higher-resolution, original image.)</sup>

[image: screencaps of the described scene][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's the beginning of Resident Evil 2 for the PS1. You can see someone playing through that sequence here:

Comment: FYI, that's RE2, not 3. The OP's pic shows Leon, and the one you posted is of Claire, both RE2 characters. Not sure why the archive you links incorrectly labeled the section RE3, but the table of contents correctly files it under 2.

Comment: @Jimmy: Thanks for the correction, I noticed that too when looking for a video. Fixed!